# Need Help In This Riddle: "The Doc Is A Lie"

Tags: steganography

So I have this riddle which contains a .docx file I opened and extracted the file and got the following contents:

[image]

In the file it was written "There is nothing here. But there is something inside"

I also have another hint "The doc is a lie. Needle in a haystack." Please help me solve this puzzle.

Comment: zip it(.rar) to open it up completely

Comment: Could you please post a plaintext listing of those file names? There's a high risk of transcription error if we try to recreate it ourselves.

Comment: Since there's often some tricky aspects seemingly unrelated, could you please upload the original files to a file sharing website?

Comment: Are the files empty?

Comment: If it's a needle in a haystack, then uncompress everything and simply do a recursive search for plaintext in any of them.